# How to find my way in this proof (fitch natural deduction proof) P → ¬Q, ¬Q → P ∴ ¬(Q ↔︎ P)

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

[image: P → ¬Q, ¬Q → P ∴ ¬(Q ↔︎ P)]
Hello all, I am very stuck in this proof. I'm still pretty much new to logic but I'm trying to get better at proofs with doing a bunch of practice proofs and this is one of them. It seems like I just can't find my way. Can anyone show me how to continue or whether I am correct up to now to begin with? Thank you. I would really appreciate if someone could show me visually.

The rules I use: ∧Intro, Elim,

∨Intro, Elim,

Conditional and bi-conditional rules

Reductio, negation elim, X, DS.

Comment: [This](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/) and [this](https://www.umsu.de/trees/) might be helpful for you in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by the OP and in the comments here, this argument is provable. It was indeed possible to find a proof.

Here is one possibility using Fitch-style natural deduction system:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, though I'm still relatively new to logic, I don't know how to use this information to finish up my proof correctly.

Comment: Another user gave me hints on this proof saying "Assume (Q ↔︎ P) hence (Q → P) and (P → Q). Combine these with P → ¬Q and ¬Q → P to prove a contradiction, and hence ¬(Q ↔︎ P) by reductio." Plus this is a practice question on a textbook, it must be doable I believe.

Comment: If $P, Q$ are both true, then $\neg Q$ is false. And then $(P \rightarrow \neg Q)$ is False.

Comment: Thank you so much, now this really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

It may be proved by contradition. The following is a formal proof:

1. $P\rightarrow\sim Q$ (premise)
2. $\sim Q\rightarrow P$ (premise)
3. $P\leftrightarrow Q$ (assumption)
4. $(P\rightarrow Q)\wedge(Q\rightarrow P)$ (equivalent form of $\leftrightarrow$, 3)
5. $P\rightarrow Q$ (simplification, 4)
6. $P$ (assumption)
7. $Q$ (M.P., 5 and 6)
8. $\sim Q$ (M.P., 1 and 6)
9. $\sim Q\wedge Q$ (adjunction, 7 and 8)
10. $\sim P$ (reductio ad absurdum, with lines 6--9 deleted)
11. $\sim\sim Q$ (M.T., 2 and 10)
12. $Q$ (Double Negation, 11)
13. $Q\rightarrow P$ (simplification, 4)
14. $\sim Q$ (M.T. 10 and 13)
15. $\sim Q\wedge Q$ (adjunction, 12 and 14)
16. $\sim(P\leftrightarrow Q)$ (reductio ad absurdum, with lines
    3--15 deleted)

Therefore, $P\rightarrow\sim Q,\,\sim Q\rightarrow P\models\sim(P\leftrightarrow Q)$

Comment: thank you! is it possible for anyone to demonstrate this using fitch notation diagram like the one i did?

Comment: It is hard to type a diagram. Therefore, I add number to each line. It should be very easy to translate the proof into fitch notation diagram.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to prove that $$(P\rightarrow \neg Q) \wedge (\neg Q\rightarrow P) \equiv \neg(P\leftrightarrow Q).$$ In fact, $$(P\rightarrow \neg Q) \wedge (\neg Q\rightarrow P) \equiv  P\leftrightarrow \neg Q,$$ so it suffices to show that $$\neg(P\leftrightarrow Q)\equiv P\leftrightarrow \neg Q.$$ We will prove the equivalent fact that $$ \neg(P\leftrightarrow \neg Q)\equiv P\leftrightarrow Q.$$
Indeed, we can use well-known congruences to find that
\begin{align*}
\neg(P\leftrightarrow \neg Q) &\equiv \neg((P\rightarrow \neg Q)\wedge (\neg Q\rightarrow P))\\
&\equiv \neg((\neg P\vee \neg Q)\wedge (Q\vee P))\\
&\equiv (\neg P\wedge \neg Q)\vee (P\wedge Q)\\
&\equiv (\neg P\vee (P\wedge Q))\wedge (\neg Q\vee (P\wedge Q))\\
&\equiv (\neg P\vee P)\wedge (\neg P\vee Q)\wedge (\neg Q\vee P)\wedge(\neg Q\vee Q)\\
&\equiv \top\wedge (\neg P\vee Q)\wedge (\neg Q\vee P)\wedge\top\\
&\equiv (\neg P\vee Q)\wedge (\neg Q\vee P)\\
&\equiv (P\rightarrow Q)\wedge (Q\rightarrow P)\\
&\equiv P\leftrightarrow Q.
\end{align*}

Comment: Hello, thanks! Is it possible if you could demonstrate this using the rules and on natural deduction proof editor? Like how i did.

Comment: @ddd I'm not familiar with that program. I just showed how to do it using logical equivalences. If you can find a way to translate it to your purposes, that's up to you.